# Automating HTTP navigation and HTML printing using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, automation

Every Monday at Work, I have the task of printing out Account analysis (portfolio analysis) and Account Positions for over 50 accounts. So i go to the page, click "account analysis", enter the account name, click "format this page for printing", Print the output (excluding company disclosures), then I go back to the account analysis page and click "positions" instead this time, the positions for that account comes up. Then I  click "format this page for printing", Print the output (excluding company disclosures).Then I repeat the process for the other 50 accounts.

I haven't taken any programming classes in the past but I heard using python to automate a html response might help me do this faster. I was wondering if that's true, and if so, how does it work? Also, are there any other programs that could enable me automate this process and save time?

Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, in theory Python can help, but it seems it will not be that easy... A question: what does the page format for printing is? Is an HTML page? A PDF file?

Comment: Clicking "format this page for printing" generates a PDF version of the page. Also, I forgot to also mention that after entering the account number on the account analysis page, I set the time frame as the previous Friday (so in this case June 1st) before hitting go and then clicking format this page for printing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for Python and its [documentation](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/documentation.html) for a good starting point in how to achieve this.

It will enable you to emulate a browser in Python and go through the steps such as filling in web-forms and doing your processing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier for you get program like autoit.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look up autoit now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run Firefox and want to avoid actual coding, the Selenium IDE firefox extension might be solution.

http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

You can record actions in browser, and replay them whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm about to check this out as well. I'll keep you updated